# Not able to convert String to InputStream for parsing XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse XML code from a server to use in Android.  The URL is working, and up to SB I get the XML.  When converting String to InputStream i get this in the logcat : java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@9e7122d
any help ? 
thanks !

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    con.setReadTimeout(60000);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    InputStream stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(sb, "UTF-8");
    Log.d(TAG, "SB " + sb);
    Log.d(TAG, "STREAM" + stream);
    return stream;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did to try sb.toString()?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Loading the entire URL into memory adds latency and wastes space, and won't fit beyond a certain size. There is no benefit. Just `return con.getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here to solve. The `ByteArrayInputStream@9e7122d` thing is just what `ByteArrayInputStream.toString()` returns.

BUT Why are you doing this? Loading the entire URL into memory adds latency and wastes space, and won't fit beyond a certain size. There is no benefit. Just return `con.getInputStream().`